# How to match the regex with p tag text using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nokogiri

I have Nodeset which is returned using `search`.

I want to find a `<p>` tag which contains "Order" or "{Income}" or "Income" or "{Income} per year", so I wrote a regular expression:

```
/(?i)order+|(\{*income\s*\}*\w*)/
```

Now I want a `<p>` tag which has the above text. How can I do this using regular expression using Nokogiri?

Comment: Show us an HTML sample demonstrating what you're talking about. In general we don't use regexp to find nodes. Both CSS and XPath allow us to look inside the text of tags, so those are the starting points.

Answer (score 3):

If you already have a `NodeSet` that you want to search further using the regex:

```
re = /(?i)order+|(\{*[Ii]ncome\s*\}*\w*)/
nodes = doc.search(…) # whatever you have already
orders = nodes.select{ |n| n.name=='p' && n.text =~ re }
```

However, I would do it like this:

```
orders = doc.xpath('//p[contains(.,"Order") or contains(.,"Income")]')
```